# Is there a way to loop through a list without making duplicate selections?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I created sample data as an image (I couldn't figure out how to put a table in):

Sample Data: this shows three stages of processing of the data
[image: Sample Data: this shows three stages of processing of the data]

I have a number of people (4 people across the top).  They have ranked 8 fruits and vegetables 1-8.  The people (pickers) are then placed in a list where they get assigned the highest ranked fruit/veggie left in the pool based on their ranking.

So for example, in the first position, Tom goes first and has Apple ranked first so he would get assigned Apple.  Then Andrew would get assigned his highest ranked fruit/veggie that was not previously selected.  I would like to automate the population of the "pick" column.

I have looked through the questions here and elsewhere for a similar example.  I thought perhaps this was possible to solve using array and index+match but I couldn't come up with a structure that worked.  I could try to process this in something outside of Excel but I think that might be even more of a headache.

I thought there would be something via VBA but that is a little out of my wheelhouse.

How might this be achieved with built in Excel tooling?

I suppose one likely option would be selected items getting removed from the list as they are selected.

This would be a one time processing, but in the real data it is dozens of people with hundreds of rankings so it is a long list to process.

I am using Excel 2016 (16.0.11328.20420 64-Bit).

Comment: You can edit your question and post some images of the results you’re expecting in each step and maybe it’s easier to understand the requirements. Also state what Excel version you’re using? And how often are you going to process the data.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I have updated the post.

Comment: Picker list is in the same order as the column headers? You could use index and use the relative row number (1,2,3...) to get the column and use countif based on the number of times the person’s name appears to get the row in which it’s located. I’m not in front of a computer, but maybe the logic can help you.

Comment: In the Andrew selection list.. Banana is the 1st selection and also his/her last selection.. is the raw data also having the same case ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is simply a requirements dump and not a question about a problem in the code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry p._phidot.  That was sloppy assembly of trying to put together some simple sample data on my end.  It was unintentional.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Sorry, that is not my intention.  I can get so far as to write out: {=INDEX($B$3:$E$10,1,(MATCH(I3:I10,$B$2:$E$2,0)))} which will give me the highest ranked option from each person down the board.  However, I am trying to find a method that steps through this such that it either a) considers the items above it in the "pick" column and excludes them or b) delete items from the array as they are selected before proceeding to the next selection.

Comment: Posted a solution using the `Filter` function and a user defined function to get the next valid search item, as the condition of uniqueness breaks the basic row wise search order. This seemed to be your main issue; if helpful, feel free to accept by ticking the hollow green checkmark just underneath the voting buttons, near the top of this answer  :-) @beard_monger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get items in a deviating search order if not unique**

Basically you follow a rowwise search order from left to right (from *Tom to Alex*) continuing with the next rank row, but *deviating* as soon as you find a duplo in current `results`.

I demonstrate an approach

- **`[1]`** assigning the complete data range to a 2-dim array `data`,
- **`[2]`** looping through the data searching for a valid (i.e. unique) item that can be written into a `results` array (see section `[c]`); these results are found via `[a]` a special helper function `getNextItem()` and `[b]` using the `Filter` function (`False` parameter to remove all current findings)
- **`[3]`** eventually writing results back to sheet.

```
Sub PickNick()
    Const Tom = 1, Alex& = 4
  ' [0] temporary array with all available picks
    Dim tmp
    tmp = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Carrots", "Grapes", "Limes", "Orange", "Squash", "Tomatoes")
  ' [1] get data from sheet (via CodeName) & prepare results array
    Dim data:  data = Sheet1.Range("B3:E10")
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(data), 1 To 1)
  ' [2] Loop through data (rank 1-2 and every picker)
    Dim rnk&, picker&
    For rnk = 1 To 2
        For picker = Tom To Alex
          ' [a] get next (unique) item via function getNextItem (see below)
            Dim nxt: nxt = getNextItem(data, results, rnk, picker)
          ' [b] filter out next item (remove it from temp array)
            tmp = Filter(tmp, nxt, False, vbTextCompare)
          ' [c] note results in array pick
            results((rnk - 1) * Alex + picker, 1) = nxt
        Next picker
    Next rnk
  ' [3] write results back to sheet (start cell H3)
    Sheet1.Range("H3").Resize(UBound(data), 1) = results

End Sub
```

**Helper function `getNextItem()` called by above procedure**

```
Function getNextItem(data, results, rnk, picker)
' Purpose: get next unique item in data, i.e. the first occurrence in results
' Method:  if not unique check the following items in the pickers data column
' Note:    called in section [2a] of main procedure PickNick
    Dim FirstOccurrence
    Dim i&, nxt
    getNextItem = "?"                   ' provide for no result
    For i = rnk To UBound(results)
        nxt = data(i, picker)
        FirstOccurrence = IsError(Application.Match(nxt, Application.Transpose(results), False))
        If FirstOccurrence Then
            getNextItem = nxt             ' return next item as function result
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image: Data Range B3:E10]